Is there a specific sense of possibility (epistemic, logical, metaphysical, etc.) under which "nothing" is possible?
When people ask Why is there something instead of nothing?, it seems that they are entertaining the possibility of nothing/nothingness, of absolutely nothing existing. Intuitively we know that we exist because we are conscious, so we cannot be nothing, so "intuitively" nothing is not possible, but maybe nothing is still possible in a different, more philosophically rigorous sense.
In what sense (if any) is nothing possible?
For example:

Is nothing epistemically possible?
Is nothing logically possible?
Is nothing metaphysically possible?
Is nothing physically possible?
Is nothing scientifically possible?
Is nothing "conceivably" (i.e., using one's imagination) possible?
etc.


Is nothing possible? Is god possible? Millions of similar questions on this site with zilions of answers. No one satisfying... maybe there is a reason for that.

"Scientifically possible" (and "epistemically possible") may not strictly speaking be coherent, because science is a methodology. Kind of like asking "is that hammerly possible". Could you use that methodology on "nothing", or to conclude that "nothing" exists? No, probably not.

Have you read this: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nothingness/#WhyTheSomRatThaNot

"Nothingness" is epistemically impossible, given your premise that "we know that we exist."
"Nothingness" is logically possible. There are no tautologies that render the concept of nothingness to be a contradiction.
"Nothingness" is metaphysically possible as long as it does not contradict any of your metaphysical commitments. In the more general sense, there are sets of metaphysical commitments that do not foreclose "nothingness."
"Nothingness" is also scientifically possible. This is because science doesn't purport to produce truth in an infallible sense. Therefore, we do not have access to a set of propositions that would foreclose scientifically that "nothingness" could have occurred instead of something. Science would not ever produce a proposition stating that "nothingness" absolutely could not have been the case. "Nothingness" as a possibility could even be outside of the set of scientifically testable hypotheses, in which case, it is all the moreso scientifically possible, since science would have nothing to say about it.
We don't know whether "nothingness" is physically impossible. All we know about physical possibility is mediated through our imperfect scientific knowledge. It may be that physically, things could not have been otherwise, rendering "nothingness" a physical impossibility. But we don't have unmediated access to such a truth.

I will not expand this to address a growing list of example questions.

"In the more general sense, there are sets of metaphysical commitments that do not foreclose "nothingness." - Can you provide at least one popular example?

""Nothingness" is also scientifically possible." - I find this hard to accept. Scientifically nothigness would need to be falsifiable to be accepted as provisionally possible, as long as the falsification tests are passed, right? But how do you even attempt to falsify nothingness? And how would nothingness pass those tests to avoid falsification?

@user80226 -- But how do you even attempt to falsify nohtingness?  Which you are you speaking of if there's nothing?

@Philomath Right, but science assumes that scientists exist, so shouldn't that axiom immediately render nothingness scientifically impossible? Or wouldn't nothigness predict that I don't exist, but I do exist, so I falsify nothingness?

@user80226 Yes, that was my thought. That also means that it is conceivably impossible. No one to conceive anything...

The SEP article on Nothingness is an excellent place to start (see comments under post). In particular, I like the following:

Some philosophers conclude ‘Why is there something rather than nothing?’ is unanswerable. They think the question stumps us by imposing an impossible explanatory demand, namely, Deduce the existence of something without using any existential premises. Logicians should feel no more ashamed of their inability to perform this deduction than geometers should feel ashamed at being unable to square the circle.

and

Why is there anything in our domain of discourse? This kind of comprehensive questioning has long been alleged to commit the fallacy of composition. Questions that can be asked of elements within a system need not be questions that can be asked of the system itself. Taking a step back to the bigger picture is fine. But when the philosopher steps back to get the biggest picture, he loses his footing. According to Immanuel Kant, the fall is misgauged as deep inquiry.

So one answer is that we take "there is something" as a brute necessity because we cannot, in principle, formulate an explanation that isn't question begging/circular by the use of existential concepts.

The below is what likely got me a downvote for some reason (no comment left). However, I am still of the mind that we need to appreciate whether we are really considering "nothingness" as a contingent or necessary state of affairs.
One issue I have with nothingness is the following modal consideration  quantified over all possible predicates P:
"There could have been nothing?"

◇[∀p∈P ¬∃x p(x) ] ?

If we are saying that even though clearly something exists, it could have been the case that nothing exists I think that is self-refuting:

If "nothingness" is only contingently a possibility, that implies that there always was something: the potential to be something; hence, nothingness can only be possible if it is necessary. Therefore, "Why is there something rather than nothing" contains the seeds of nothing's demise: contingent nothingness is not actually "nothing". Only necessary nothingness is coherent and it doesn't admit a choice in the matter.

If we ignore "potentiality" as a some-thing, then we'd need to consider that fact that something happened vs nothing is a brute contingency; again, it is brute like before because "nothing" removes all domains of discourse and terms, so we strip away our ability to formulate explanations.

Upvoted to compensate the downvote, +1.

@user80226 ^_^ !!
